# Faulty behaviour on Lenovo Legion Ubuntu 18.04 when connecting HDMI

Tags: 18.04, hdmi

I am using a Lenovo Legion Y530 with Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS. Getting the following information when connecting the a monitor to the HDMI port. Following screen appears directly after connecting HDMI.

[image: Faulty Behaviour]

Comment: It has Nvidia graphics. Have you installed the drivers? Which version?

Comment: How can I check that?

Comment: So, you don't know whether or not you installed drivers? Interesting...

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia It is a new user after all.... **craft**: When the HDMI monitor is unplugged you can use the laptop normally?